# Switching classes when clicked for a div in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Basically, I have a div block whose class I want replaced on click.

My HTML:

```
<div class="lol">       
</div>
```

My jQuery code:

```
$('.lol').toggleClass('troll');
```

This outputs:

```
<div class="lol troll">
</div>
```

**How do I completely replace the class name lol with troll?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass) method

```
$('.lol').removeClass('lol').addClass('troll');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want only replace one class by another, you can use:

```
$(".lol").removeClass("lol").addClass("troll");
```

Answer (score 0):

Either `removeClass` "lol" before `addClass` "troll", or toggle them both:

```
$('.lol').toggleClass('lol').toggleClass('troll');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle both classes

```
$('.lol').toggleClass('troll').toggleClass('lol'​);​
```

And you can do it even shorter like this

```
$('.lol').toggleClass('troll lol');​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PCWtY/2/) (The alertboxes show what's in the result window's body)

Answer (score 0):

In case you're in a situation where you want to replace multiple class names with just one, you could do the following...

```
$(".lol").attr("class", "troll");
```

It simply rewrites the class name.